# Instruct Kafka Consumer App To Start Reading From Offset

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

If I have an application AppA that contains a Kafka consumer class, is it possible to instruct this consumer's behaviour pragmatically? For example, I may want to tell AppA over a rest API (or even via another topic) to wake up and begin consuming and processing messages from TopicB at offset or timestamp X and to stop at offset or timestamp Y. I may tell it to read the same sections of a topic repeatedly to perform different analysis of the data and I might want the consumer to sit idle when it's not performing an instruction.

Is it possible to control a consumer in this fashion? Essentially, I'm interested to know if I can read sections of topics on demand to produce processing/reports on its contents.. kind of in a similar to way to querying a relational DB via an admin console I guess.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd recommend writing your data (with offset) to an actual database if you want to be performing constant range queries on the data. Especially when Kafka can remove those offsets due to retention policies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kafka consumer is able to consume topics at arbitrary positions.

You can use the [`seek()`](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seek(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition,long)) method to start consuming from a specific offset. You can also use the [`offsetsForTimes()`](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#offsetsForTimes(java.util.Map)) method to find the offsets for a specific timestamp.

You can combine these two methods to consume specific sections of topics on demand.