# CDC(Change Data Capture) with Kafka

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, cdc

I want to implement CDC with kafka: DB1->kafka-> various sinks (ie: s3, DB, other kafka consumer).
One of the use cases is to restore a given table only with events from given period of time.

Ie: for TBL1 all events are in kafka, initial load and deltas. I want to restore in given sink(ie. s3, db) this table only with events from date1-date2.

How would you approach this, additionally to restoring full state?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Debezium](https://debezium.io) to do an initial snapshot of a database table, then track new changes to Kafka.

There is no available tool out-of-the-box that will copy data to/from a Kafka topic between two time intervals; you'd need to [write that yourself (from Kafka)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72205304/instruct-kafka-consumer-app-to-start-reading-from-offset), or using a range-query + filter from your database/filesystem to a KafkaProducer. The Confluent S3 Source Connector, for example, will read all files (written by the S3 sink), and the JDBC (I assume this is what you mean by "db") Source Connector needs internal manipulation and a custom query to start/end at any timestamp/record.